# Navigation Drawer and Bottom Bar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have implemented a navigation drawer and a bottom navigation bar.

My problem is that the navigation drawer is as heigh as the contents frame height. So when the navigation drawer is opened, the bottom navigation bar will get partially hidden just like the contents of the main layout.

I have tried the following to overcome this issue:

- Get the height of the bottom navigation bar.
- Set the height of the navigation drawer to (drawer's height - bar's height)

But this way the drawer does not know about the changes of the height.

Here is what I want to accomplish:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have our layout something like that:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- The main content view -->

     <!-- The navigation drawer -->

   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

   <!-- Your bottom bar --!>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I thought DrawerLayout must be the root element of XML file!

Comment: To be honest i've never tried having it as not the root layout, but if that doesn't work, have it in its own fragment and have the containing fragment or activity carry your bottom bar

Comment: Put everything inside RelativeLayout except bottom bar and it will work. Great!